# Need help utilizing Beeblex validating in-app purchases with xCode

Tags: xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase

Has anyone had success using Beeblex to validate in-app purchases?  I have an app that is already live in the app-store with in-app purchases enabled and working.  In light of the recent hacking news concerning in-app purchases I am attempting to update it to use Beeblex to validate purchases.  The problem is that Beeblex always returns a result saying that Apple claims the purchase to be invalid.  I am hoping someone on here is successfully using Beeblex and can post a working example.  I am following their advice to let the purchase go completely through, then validate it.  I basically just cut and pasted their code right off their website, so not sure what I could do differently.

```
- (void) validatePurchaseOrRestore
```

{

```
//The transaction has been reported as complete for a new purchase of the upgrade.  I now make use of Beeblex
//to verify the receipt to ensure the purchase is legit.
if (![BBXIAPTransaction canValidateTransactions])
{
    transactionResult = 4;
    return; // There is no connectivity to reach the server.
    // You should try the validation at a later date.
}

BBXIAPTransaction *bbxTransaction = [[BBXIAPTransaction alloc] initWithTransaction:transactionCopy];
bbxTransaction.useSandbox;

[bbxTransaction validateWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
     if (bbxTransaction.transactionVerified)
     {
         if (bbxTransaction.transactionIsDuplicate)
         {

             // The transaction is valid, but duplicate - it has already been
             // sent to Beeblex in the past.
             transactionResult = 1;

         }
         else
         {
             // The transaction has been successfully validated
             // and is unique.

             NSLog(@"Transaction data: %@", bbxTransaction.validatedTransactionData);
             transactionResult = 0;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         // Check whether this is a validation error, or if something
         // went wrong with Beeblex.

         if (bbxTransaction.hasServerError)
         {                 
             // The error was not caused by a problem with the data, but is
             // most likely due to some transient networking issues.
             transactionResult = 4;
         }
         else
         {                 
             // The transaction supplied to the validation service was not valid according to Apple.
             transactionResult = 3;
             purchaseDidFail = TRUE;
         }    
     }
 }];
```

}